# jquery autocomplete from database showing no results

Tags: jquery, database, autocomplete

I've used the following code to get the jquery autocomplete values from a database:

```
$( ".ui-widget" ).autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2
    });
```

search.php consists of the following.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'airports2', '*******', 'airports2');
$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$query = "SELECT airport FROM airports WHERE airport LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY airport 

ASC";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
    $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['name'].'"}';
}
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
?>
```

when I enter a search term (which matches a database entry), I can see a small whitespace, without any results, as i he didn't find any.

Thanks a lot in advance,

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: thank you, but now the whitespace is not even showing at all.

Comment: @SWeinberger Did you make both of our changes?

Comment: For the moment, the table in the database (which, for now, only consists of a table with a single column), contains only the following two entries (so you can test it).
'Brussels, Belgium - National (BRU)'
'Amsterdam, Netherlands - Schiphol (AMS)'

What's interesting, it only shows the whitespace results when a part of one of those entries is entered (so he does indeed find them apparently), otherwise it shows nothing at all.

Comment: Did anyone manage to test it and see for themselves what I mean?

Comment: Do you have change as i have post removing the while? I see yet "value" when the only field that you select is the airport

Comment: I changed it before, but I see nothing working. I changed it again, so what you see on the site now is with your code.

Comment: What php version do you have? if you haven't a 5.3< version change fetch_all with a while, like this while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $json[] = $row['airport'];

Comment: Indeed, I have PHP version 5.2.17.
Can you please be more clear with what you mean? Do you mean to substitute in the original code or in the one you proposed?
Thanks again.

Comment: Remove the line with fetch_all() and sostitute it with that while

Comment: you mean like this?
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $json[] = $row['airport'];;
echo json_encode($json);

Comment: Just $result = $mysqli->query($query); while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) $json[] = $row['airport']; echo json_encode($json);

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation in PHP requires the `.` operator.

```
$query = "SELECT airport FROM airports WHERE airport LIKE '%" . $text . "%' ORDER BY airport
```

Comment: @KevinBowersox php when you use the double quotes doesn't require concatenation for vars, instead for the apostrophe yes